# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

We already know that  $\forall \alpha>1$, we have  $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^\alpha}<+\infty$$ I’m considering adding some little amounts, say$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) $$ I’m not sure if series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is convergent. Intuitively speaking, $o(1/n)$ is considered “smaller” than $1/n$, so it should converge. However I’m quite sure this statement is not correct(lol). Can anybody give me a counter example?

Comment: $f(n)=\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$ is $o(\frac{1}{n})$ , but the sum is still diverging.

Comment: I do not think that the sum with $o(\frac{1}{n})$ is a well-defined expression.

Comment: Note that being smaller is not enough. For *any* diverging series we can find a series where the terms are smaller and it still diverges. The classical examples are $\frac{1}{n}\to \frac{1}{n\log(n)} \to \frac{1}{n\log(n)\log\log(n)} \to \ldots$. All of these series diverge (integral test) even though the next term in the series is smaller by a factor that goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$!

Comment: I agree. I just want to express a sum with terms “smaller than” $o(1/n)$. @Peter

Answer (score 4):

We have that

$$\frac1{n\log n}=o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right),\quad \frac1{n^2}=o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

then we can't conclude whether $\sum o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ diverges or converges.

Answer (score 1):

In fact，for positive numbers $\alpha$, when $\alpha$$\leq$1, we have $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n (log\ n)^\alpha}=+\infty$$
when $\alpha$>1
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n (log\ n)^\alpha}<+\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar exercise problem in Zorich's textbook:

If $a_{n}\ge a_{n+1}>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges then $a_{n}=o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ as $n\to\infty$.

So I believe $o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is only a necessary condition to converge.